# PHP decoding json to xml because of special characters

Tags: php, json, xml

I'm trying to convert a json into an xml string which I have to store in a mysql database. This doesn't work because of special characters within the json.

As you can see in the example code I found a way to see a fine string in my browser.

```
<?php
// example response
$json = '{"examples":"„Plötzlich“ los – und (†30) Wird’s H&M"}';

// decode ...
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);

// ... to convert it
$xmlData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><item>';
$xmlData .= iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', $jsonArray['examples']);
$xmlData .= '</item>';

//echo ('without encoding: ' . $jsonArray['examples'] . ' ... without encoding: ' . iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1252', $jsonArray['examples']));
echo($xmlData);

/*
 * with the first echo the xml string looks like 
 * <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><item>„Plötzlich“ los – und (†30) Wird’s H&M</item>
 * 
 * without the first echo it looks like 
 * <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><item>�Pl�tzlich� los � und (�30) Wird�s H&M</item><item>„Plötzlich“ los – und (†30) Wird’s H&M</item>
 */
?>
```

But trying to write that string to the database will stop at the first �.

Where is my fault? How to keep the special characters?

Comment: Sounds like you did not properly save the script file _as UTF-8_ ...

Comment: I saved a new file as UTF-8 and it doesn't work, too ... :-(

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution ... it was just an additional option within json_decode:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```